# Bash script to Comparing list of variable filenames from one txt file to another and do something in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My aim is to read the filenames in temp11 file one by one and compare it with the filenames in the tj_mail.txt

if it matches, do nothing , if it doesn't, move the file from the from destination to another.

temp 11 has abc.xlsx and tj_mail.txt has /path1/path2/abc.xlsx

so as they are not matching, it is supposed to perform the Move operation

```
cat /mae/SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/Airtime_Activation/temp11 | while IFS="" read -r -d $'\0' file;
do
    read "${file?}"
    if grep -qF "$$file" /mae/scripts/tj_mail.txt;then
    :
    else
        mv $file /marketsource/SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/Airtime_Activation/newthings
    fi
done
```

There are no error, but doing nothing too, it seems to be not reading the file

Comment: [how to read a file in bash line by line](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). But really, it looks like you want `comm`.

Comment: Why do you have two `$` in `$$file`? Is that in the real script or a copying error.

Comment: What is `read "${file?}"` supposed to mean?

Comment: @KamilCuk - thank you, but tried this way too... "while IFS= read -r line;" but not much of a use

Comment: @Barmar - i am trying to read variable file, hence the "${file?}" and same with grep too $$, I have explored online and wrote it, please suggest me the correct one!

Comment: Why do you need another `read` statement? `$file` is the filename that was read from `temp11`, just use `grep -qF "$file"`

Comment: @Barmar tried it, it isnt working Barmar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use `read` and `grep`. Use `comm` to compare the two files and get the files that are missing, and pass those to `mv`.

```
comm -23 <(sort /mae/SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/Airtime_Activation/temp11) <(sort /mae/scripts/tj_mail.txt) | 
    xargs mv -t /marketsource/SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/Airtime_Activation/newthings
```

Comment: it is working when ran in linux machine, but when calling from informatica, that command isnt executing! is there any other code to do it in another way

Comment: I'm not familiar with Informatica and how it works.

Comment: Make sure it's using `bash` as the shell. `<(...)` is a `bash` extension, it's not available in `sh`.

Comment: If you can't use process substitution, you can write the sorted files to temporary files and then compare them with `comm`.

Comment: I think, i can able to troubleshoot the problem, its not about the 'comm' command, it is that informatica couldnt perform the operation because it has not been feeded with the location where the files are located. so it is searching for the default /bin/bash directory. I have tried using the below line in the script to tell the bash that the script file is in that directory.. But seems it isnt recognizing..is the format corect ?
alias tj_new_test.ksh="/mae/SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/Airtime_Activation"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The filenames are absolute pathnames, it doesn't need to be told where they exist in any other way.

Comment: Aliases aren't normally expanded in scripts, and aliases are just used to abbreviate the command, not parameters.

Comment: Solved it! worked perfectly now, i've used (cd /path ; command) . Thanks a ton @Barmar

cd /mae/SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/Airtime_Activation ; comm -23 <(sort /mae/SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/Airtime_Activation/temp11) <(sort /mae/scripts/tj_mail.txt) | 
    xargs mv -t /marketsource/SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/Airtime_Activation/newthings )